# How Can I Use php code in this manner

Tags: php

```
$marks . $count = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['marks$count']);
```

I want to use `$count` (variable) in (`$con . $_POST[]`)

But as I tried it gave me error. I am very new for php coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
for($count=0;!empty($_POST['marks'][$count]);$count++){
$marks[$count] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['marks'][$count]);
}
```

At the end of the cycle, array $marks will contain all escaped values of array $_POST['marks'].

Comment: Ahh I guess this kind of helps me see what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can't concatenate before assignment. The proper ways to use string variable concatenation:

```
$marks .= $count; //option 1
$newVar = $marks.$count; //option 2
$marks = $marks.$count; //option 3
$newVar = "$marks$count"; //option 4
```

The way you are attempting, there is no clear variable to make the assignment to. The value on the right side of the equal is being assigned to what's on the left side of the equal sign. Two variables on the left side is ambiguous.